# Days of Week as XML attributes?

Tags: c#, xml

So I'm working on a calendar-based application in C#, and I need to get the days of the week that an event is to repeat itself (for instance, every Monday/Friday).

I'm storing the events in XML, defined similarly as such:

```
<events>
  <event startDate = "Insert Date Here" endDate = "Insert Date Here">Event Name</event>
</events>
```

How could I simply and reliably store and retrieve specific days of the week in this XML file?

If it helps, I'll be specifying the days of the week by a `CheckBoxList`, which I will be looping through to check for, well, checks.

Comment: How about `RepeatDays="Monday,Tuesday"` or `<event ...><RepeatOn>Monday</RepeatOn></event>` or `RepeatOn="256"` where 256 is a bitmasked value?

Comment: I see, so I could make a string value out of each checkbox, store those strings in one attribute, then use if statements and parsing to search the string for specific values? Or would that be overkill with upwards of 7 if statements?

Comment: The bitmask version is the shortest but least readable. It depends on what your use case is.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not skilled enough to really make use of bitmask. I'm embarrassed to say I'm not really familiar with the concept.

Comment: A bitmask takes advantage of binary ones and zeroes for use as a set of flags.  For example, if you had an event that repeated on Monday/Tuesday/Saturday, the mask would look like `0110001` (one bit per day of the week; 1 if the event is repeated on the given day, 0 if not), which would render as the integer 49.  After reading that value, your program would get the days of the week by accessing the bit values of the integer.  But as @DavidG says, it's not very readable - in XML or in the code that reads it.  Better to use a comma-separated list of days.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably just have to do 7 parses for specific days in the recurring frequency function that tells when an event repeats, and have it check that the current calendar day it's checking matches within each if statement that parses it. All as one "weekDays" Attribute.

Comment: Actually, what I could do is check the current day's DayOfWeek.ToString() and parse for that within that attribute. If true, add the event. Much less repetitive code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following from [this XML library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/)

```
XElement a = new XElement("root");
a.Set("day", DayOfWeek.Thursday, true); // true = set as attribute of 'a'
DayOfWeek day = a.Get("day", DayOfWeek.Friday); // DayOfWeek.Friday is default
Console.WriteLine(day);
```

Output:

```
Thursday
```

Generated XML:

```
<root day="Thursday" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to serialize the values as ints then use them with an enum in the C# code (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ect). You could also use the words.

Then you can read them and use the built in [enum values as listed in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in code to maintain readability. Which, by the way,

> if cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates
>   DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday).

If you provide specifics on how you are reading the data from the xml into your C# app I can provide more specifics.

Comment: don't forget about invariantnes ... ie US starts with sunday

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that and checked the msdn link I referenced and saw that they start with 0 as Sunday as cast to an int. I edited my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you're injecting fragility into your design. Suppose that your <event>'s day-of-week (DoW) and date disagree? What does your app do?

I think it's better to calculate the day of week based on that initial date:

```
        var repeatingEvents = new List<DateTime>();
        repeatingEvents.Add(new DateTime(2015, 4, 15));
        for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            repeatingEvents.Add(repeatingEvents[0].AddDays(7*i));
        }
```

This gives you 5 events on the same day of week without having to worry about what the actual DoW is.

If you're absolutely insistent on serializing DoW, look to DateTime: It already supports a [DayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function, and has a [DayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum for your use.

Comment: Unfortunately, one type of event is to be repeated over several months several times a week. And the events will be user-defined, so I can't predict what types of patterns will be used. For all I know, the user could set one up that is every tuesday, wednesday, and saturday while another may only set an event to repeat on monday and tuesday. So I'm still going to have to get the days they set and write the events based on that.